# What is the difference between emotions, intuition and affect?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, intuition, cognition

From what I know, intuition is affect-based. But how do they differ?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between affect and feeling?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16144/7001) and [Difference between Instinct and Intuition](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/767/7001).

Answer (score 3):

**Affect** is a fundamental feature of consciousness and is a mental representation of input from the body to the brain.  Affect corresponds to feelings of (un)pleasantness and activation (arousal).

**Emotions** are conceptualizations (interpretations) of your affect in a given context.  You might feel pleasant and highly aroused (an affective feeling) on a roller coaster, and your conceptualization of that affect in that context would be "excitement" (an emotional feeling).  In this sense, emotions are what we would traditionally consider to be "cognitive."

[Source](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v16/n7/abs/nrn3950.html)

Under this scheme, **intuition** doesn't really have a direct, formal relationship to affect or emotion, although intuitions are often affective (well, pretty much everything is affective).  But [see here](https://www.dshs-koeln.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Institute/Kognitions-_und_Sportspielforschung/Publikationen/Paper/Pretz_Brookings_Carlson_Humbert_Roy_Jones___Memmert_2014.pdf) for a more informed discussion of the literature.

Answer (score 2):

### Intuition

 is

> the ability to acquire knowledge without proof, evidence, or conscious reasoning, or without understanding how the knowledge was acquired ([Miriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition); [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intuition))

### Affect

 is

> the experience of feeling or emotion. (Hogg, et al. 2010)

### Emotion

 is

> any relatively brief conscious experience characterized by intense mental activity and a high degree of pleasure or displeasure (Cabanac, 2002; Schacter, 2011). Scientific discourse has drifted to other meanings and there is no consensus on a definition.

An **emotion** can be an **affect** as a result of **intuition**

---

### References

Cabanac, M. (2002). *What is emotion?* In: Behavioural Processes 60(2): 69-83
DOI: [10.1016/S0376-6357(02)00078-5](http://doi.org/10.1016/S0376-6357(02)00078-5) PMID: [12426062](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12426062)
**Free PDF Available** from [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11040893_What_is_emotion)

Hogg, M.A., Abrams, D., & Martin, G.N. (2010). *Social cognition and attitudes*. In: Martin, G.N., Carlson, N.R., Buskist, W., (Ed.), Psychology (pp 646-677). Harlow:Pearson Education Limited.

Schacter, D. L., Gilbert, D.T., Wegner, D.M. (2011). Psychology Second Edition. New York, NY:Worth Publishers. p. 310. ISBN 978-1-4292-3719-2.

Answer (score 0):

[Intuition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuition) is unrelated to the other two, because it is an aspect of [cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognition). Meanwhile [affect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect_(psychology)) is "the experience... of [emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion)", meaning that these terms are more or less synonymous.

Comment: "Intuition is unrelated to the other two" - What about the issues of emotion caused by the outcomes of intuition?

Comment: By "unrelated" I mean that there is a clear conceptual distinction between affect and cognition. Of course cognition (including intuition) can impact affect, and also vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Intuition: my environment is totally uncorrelated with anything I am aware of but it still leads me to believe something is about to happen.

Emotion: a state of mind evoked by physical sensations, particular memories, and expectations of the future.

Affect: the outward manifestation of my emotions which may or may not be deliberate.

Comment: Welcome - can you add sources to your definitions?

Comment: Yeah, sources would help, I don't think these definitions are correct. -1